# Evitar doble peticiones en mi API Rest

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails, rest, requests, peticiones

Se puede evitar que una apliación envíe dos veces una petición a mi API Rest deshabilitando el botón en el formulario tras el primer envío.  Eso funciona, pero dependo de que la aplicación cliente haga ese trabajo.  Pero si la aplicación no deshabilita el botón y por error el usuario envía dos veces la petición, ¿cómo debería mi API Rest responder a eso?

Gracias.

Comment: Podrías revisar [este artículo](https://blog.eq8.eu/article/rails-api-authentication-with-spa-csrf-tokens.html), puede darte pautas de cómo implementar CSRF para SPA (que también puede aplicarse a API´s)

Comment: No si están mal interpretando mi pregunta.  CSRF se refiere a falsificación de petición en sitios cruzados; eso no es lo que estoy preguntando.  Lo que quiero saber es como debería reaccionar mi API Rest si un cliente válido por error envía dos veces la misma petición, por ejemplo, si por error dio dos veces click al botón de enviar.

Comment: Si, tengo claro cuál es el objetivo de CSRF. Basé mi comentario en la respuesta de ordago porque me parece que es una opción válida para limitar clientes a una petición, lo malo es que tendrían que enviar un nuevo `xsrf-token` cada vez que realizan un request, lo cual es poco común para una API, pero es una opción válida. Lo otro podría ser que limites los requests recibidos desde una IP a cierta cantidad por x cantidad de tiempo, que es algo que he visto en otras API´s, aunque esto es algo que configuras desde tu nginx/apache y en realidad desconozco como se hace.

Comment: Ahora, respondiendo a tu pregunta, si recibe dos requests idénticos, debería procesarlos de igual manera. Eso es un problema del cliente y no del servidor, ya que no tienes forma de saber si el 2do request es válido o no.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes implementar es algún tipo de protección contra CSRF.

Consiste simplemente en que cuando renderices el formulario, guardes en un campo oculto un token aleatorio, que tendrás guardado en la variable de sesión del usuario. Imagínate algo asi:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="1d334kdd"/>
```

Cuando el usuario mande el formulario, al recibir la primera respuesta verificas que el token que le mandaste al renderizar el formulario coincide con lo que que tienes guardado en la sesión; y si coincide, inmediatamente invalidar ese token (generar un token nuevo). Ejemplo:

```
Renderizo formulario con token 1d334kdd

Primera vez que pulsa botón -> Se envía token 1d334kdd -> Coincide con sesión "1d334kdd" == "1d334kdd" -> OK, invalido token (nuevo token = "4554jj221").

Segunda vez que pulsa botón -> Se envía token 1d334kdd -> No coincide con sesión "1d334kdd" != "4554jj221"-> No acepto esta petición.
```

Cuando hayas acabado de gestionar la petición y vuelvas a renderizar el siguiente formulario, le pones el nuevo token porque ya estarías preparado para aceptar una nueva petición.

No conozco ruby on rails, por lo que no se si esto está implementado en alguna librería, framework, etc, eso a lo mejor te puede ayudar otra persona.